# numcases environment with showlabels package

Tags: numbering, cases, showlabels

I just discovered the environment [`numcases`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cases), which upgrades the package cases allowing to number the different cases.

I am also currently using the [`showlabels`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showlabels) package, which puts the name of the label on the PDF, right where you put it in the TeX file. Very useful feature, especially when writing a long document and you want to get the tag name from the PDF scrolling up a page rather than open another TeX file and search for the equation!

Unfortunately, I can't get the `numcases` environment to work properly with the `showlabels` package. In particular, I cannot give a label to the last case, otherwise I get the error "Incompatible list can't be unboxed". However, without the `showcases` package, everything works smoothly. It also works smoothly if I don't label the last case, but of course that's not optimal, cause I need to label all the cases...

Here's an example. Comment/uncomment the line where the `showlabels` package is included to see the behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showlabels}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}{}
a & b \label{a}\\
c & d \label{b}
\end{numcases}

\end{document}
```

Does anybody know a workaround for this? I would be fine also with a way to avoid `numcases` (while getting the same result).

Comment: please always post a small document that demonstrates the problem, add it to your question, using the `{}` button in the editor to mark code sections.

Comment: This is now, finally, fixed. You may want to try showlabels 1.7b1 from http://purl.org/nxg/dist/showlabels or https://bitbucket.org/nxg/showlabels/downloads – thanks for reporting this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot understand why lines of a `cases` environment should be separately numbered. However, you get the effect with `empheq`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{showlabels}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{alignat=2}
&a\qquad & b \label{a}\\
&c\qquad & d \label{b}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, when you have a system of equations and you want to refer to one of those, it's more elegant to have a number like 1.2 rather than "the second equation in 1". And yes, align does that, but I also like the braket in front. =)

Comment: @bartgol I disagree. But the document is yours. `;-)`

Comment: Well, if the system has quite a few equations and you want to refer to one in particular, it is more effective to say 1.5 rather than ask the reader to count the equations. Perhaps that's just me. As you said, to each its own. ;-)

Comment: While this apparently worked in 2014, it now seems to produces two pairs of partially overlapping labels.

Comment: I blame `empheq`, of course. `:-)`

Comment: @Circumscribe See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461005/showlabels-problems-with-subequations#comment1159447_461005

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to use `showkeys` instead of `showlabels` (we've had healthy rivalry for a few decades:-) but if you want to stick with the opposition you can add some defensive coding to `numcases` so that the additional boxes don't break it:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\usepackage{cases}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{numcases}[1]%
{$$\numc@opts \setbox\z@\hbox
  {\advance\c@equation\@ne\def\@currentlabel{\p@equation\theequation}% local
  $\displaystyle {#1\null}\m@th$}%
 \numc@setsub 
 \setbox\tw@\vbox\bgroup
  \stepcounter{equation}\def\@currentlabel{\p@equation\theequation}% 
  \global\@eqnswtrue\m@th \everycr{}\tabskip\numc@left\let\\\@eqncr
  \halign to\dimen@ii \bgroup \kern\wd\z@ \kern14\p@ % assume width of brace
    \tabskip\z@skip \global\@eqcnt\@ne $\displaystyle{##}$\hfil 
   &\global\@eqcnt\tw@ \skip@10\p@ \advance\skip@\tw@\arraycolsep \hskip\skip@
    ##\unskip\hfil\tabskip\@centering% \unskip removes space if no explanations
   &\global\@eqcnt\thr@@\hbox to\z@\bgroup\hss##\egroup\tabskip\z@skip\cr
}{\@@eqncr \egroup % end \halign, which does not contain first column or brace
 \global\advance\c@equation\m@ne 
%Measure the natural width of the alignment
 \unskip\unpenalty\unskip\unpenalty \setbox\z@\lastbox % grab last line
%%%%% NEW TEST
\ifvbox\z@
\setbox\tw@\box\z@
\setbox\z@\lastbox
 \nointerlineskip \copy\z@ % then put it back
 \nointerlineskip \copy\tw@ % then put it back
\else
 \nointerlineskip \copy\z@ % then put it back
\fi
%%%%% END NEW
 \global\dimen@i\wd\z@ 
 \setbox\z@\hbox{\hskip-\numc@left\unhbox\z@}% Measure its natural width
 \ifdim \wd\z@<\dimen@i \global\dimen@i\wd\z@ \fi
\egroup% end \vbox (box\tw@, box\z@ is restored to LHS)
\hbox to\dimen@ii{\m@th % assemble the whole equation
  \hskip\numc@left 
  \hbox to\dimen@i{$\displaystyle \box\z@ % parameter #1
    \dimen@\ht\tw@ \advance\dimen@\dp\tw@ % get size of brace
    \left\{\vcenter to\dimen@{\vfil}\right.\n@space % make brace
    $\hfil}\hskip\@centering % finished first part (filled whole line)
  \kern-\dimen@ii % backspace the full width
  $\vcenter{\box\tw@}$% overlay the alignment
 }% end the \hbox to\dimen@ii
\numc@resetsub
$$\global\@ignoretrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}{}
a & b {\label{a}}\\
c & d {\label{b}}
\end{numcases}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting option the showkeys. I think I will go with the empheq option proposed by egreg, just cause I was not super fond of numcases to strt with (I had to throw in dollar signs to insert math expressions).

Just out of curiosity, what's the up/down side of using showkeys vs showlabels? They look pretty much the same to me at first look...

Comment: @bartgol they are similar but patch in the output in different ways, both can break things, showkeys got lucky in this case (actually I think it is generally more robust, but then, I would) shame you gave the points to egreg though: he has far too many already:-)

Comment: LoL: you guys are both in the 100k range. No need for change... ;-)

Thanks for your feedback though. I will definitely consider showkeys in the future. =)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hrmmmm, I've made this slightly more robust, I think, in 1.7b1 – the rivalry continues!

Comment: @NormanGray :-)