# showlabels problems with subequations

Tags: numbering, labels, subequations, showlabels

I would like to resume the post on the [`\usepackage{showlabels}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460265/use-showlabel-package-with-newcommand-loadnote) for a moment

working on some things, I found this [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165685/subequations-and-array-in-braces) very handy, but I saw that when I activate the `\usepackage{showlabels}`, from these problems. what could it be?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{showlabels} %%<------

\begin{document}
We refer to the subequation \eqref{eq079.1} end \eqref{eq079.2} and the whole equation (\ref{eq:all}).
\begin{subequations}
    \label{eq:all}
\begin{empheq}[left={\empheqlbrace\,}]{align}
    &\rho = \rho+\quad \text{con}\quad \tilde{\rho}\ll\rho_{0}  \label{eq079.1}
    \\ \nonumber \\ 
    &p = p_{0} + \tilde{p} \quad \text{con}\quad p_{_{0}} = \cdots\quad  \text{e}\quad  \tilde{p}\ll p_{0}\label{eq079.2}
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, apparently something about the interaction between `showlabels` and `empheq` has changed since 2014. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211899/156366), which worked back then, now suffers from the same problem.

Comment: With TeX Live 2015 the output is correct, it starts to be mangled with TeX Live 2016 on.

Comment: @egreg therefore, it does not have a solution, but it is a problem between the two packages.

Comment: A change to `showlabels` for enhancing compatibility with `amsmath` results in the label printed twice, one without the shift due to `\empheqlbrace\,` and one with. Indeed, if you remove the `left=` option, you'll not see the issue, because the double labels overprint each other. I can't see a workaround, sorry. Both `showlabels` and `empheq` hook in `\maketag@@@` and conflict arises.

Comment: Hrumph: some fraction of my grey hairs are due to my tiptoeing around `\maketag@@@` trying not to get my (and showlabels') heels bitten. I've opened an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/nxg/showlabels/issues/11) noting this, and I'll address that when I can.  The incompatibility does appear to have been a change between `showlabels` v1.7 and v1.8, so a bit of bisection should help me narrow it down further. Thanks for finding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `showkeys` instead

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{showkeys} %%<------

\begin{document}
We refer to the subequation \eqref{eq079.1} end \eqref{eq079.2} and the whole equation (\ref{eq:all}).
\begin{subequations}
    \label{eq:all}
\begin{empheq}[left={\empheqlbrace\,}]{align}
    &\rho = \rho+\quad \text{con}\quad \tilde{\rho}\ll\rho_{0}  \label{eq079.1}
    \\ \nonumber \\ 
    &p = p_{0} + \tilde{p} \quad \text{con}\quad p_{_{0}} = \cdots\quad  \text{e}\quad  \tilde{p}\ll p_{0}\label{eq079.2}
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

See
[numcases environment with showlabels package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211896/numcases-environment-with-showlabels-package/211899#comment506557_211901)

:-)

Comment: I must confess that the form of `\usepackage{showlabels}`, is much more orderly, but this is more effective. I do not like the rectangles aesthetically, thanks for the suggestion